# Исключение CaptchaNeedException не обрабатывается (авторизация ВК, C#, библиотека VkNet)

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

Делаю авторизацию ВК библиотекой VkNet. По идее при необходимости ввести капчу выбрасывается VkNet.Exception.CaptchaNeedException, однако в моём случае выбрасывается VkNet.Exception.VkApiException, сообщающий что "Требуется ввод капчи", полазил в инете, путёвого ничего не нашёл. Может я в чём-то допустил ошибку? Помогите плиз, вот сам код авторизации:

```
// инициализация полей

try
        {
            vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams
            {
                ApplicationId = appID,
                Login = login,
                Password = password,
                Settings = settings
            });
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.CaptchaNeededException cne)
        {
            // пропускает, не обрабатывается сам CaptchaNeedException
            // обработка, вывод капчи и т. д.
        }
        catch (VkNet.Exception.VkApiException exc)
        {
            // а здесь выбрасывает VkApiException и пишет "Требуется ввод капчи"
        }
```

Comment: что пишет в Inner Exception объекта exc?

Comment: Выдаёт такую ошибку: 
_**System.NullReferenceException**: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта._    Ничего ещё не нашёл..

Comment: Вобщем  забил на авторизацию по логпассу, перешёл на токен

Comment: возможно у вас один из объектов пустой, посмотрите что находится в settings, и там есть перечесление Settings.All, попробуйте с ним.